# How can I check if the PowerShell profile script is running from an SSH session?

Tags: powershell, ssh, openssh, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to work around a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1677) in *Win32-OpenSSH*, where `-NoProfile -NoLogo` is not respected when using pwsh.exe (Core) and logging in remotely via SSH/SCP. One way (of several) I tried, was to add the following in the very beginning of my **`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`** profile.

```
function IsInteractive {
    $non_interactive = '-command', '-c', '-encodedcommand', '-e', '-ec', '-file', '-f'
    -not ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() | Where-Object -FilterScript {$PSItem -in $non_interactive})
}
# No point of running this script if not interactive
if (-not (IsInteractive)) {
    exit
}
...
```

However, this didn't work with a remote SSH, because when using `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` with pwsh.exe, all you get back is:
**`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.dll`**
regardless whether or not you are in an *interactive* session.

Another way I tried, was to scan through the process tree and look for the `sshd` parent, but that was also inconclusive, since it may run in another thread where `sshd` is not found as a parent.
So then I tried looking for other things. For example `conhost`. But on one machine `conhost` starts before `pwsh`, whereas on another machine, it starts after...then you need to scan up the tree and maybe find an explorer instance, in which case it is just a positive that the previous process is interactive, but not a definite non-interactive current process session.

```
function showit() {
    $isInter = 'conhost','explorer','wininit','Idle',
    $noInter = 'sshd','pwsh','powershell'
    $CPID = ((Get-Process -Id $PID).Id)

    for (;;) {
        $PNAME = ((Get-Process -Id $CPID).Name) 
        Write-Host ("Process: {0,6} {1} " -f $CPID, $PNAME) -fore Red -NoNewline
        $CPID = try { ((gwmi win32_process -Filter "processid='$CPID'").ParentProcessId) } catch { ((Get-Process -Id $CPID).Parent.Id) } 
        
        if ($PNAME -eq "conhost") {
            Write-Host ": interactive" -fore Cyan
            break;
        }
        if ( ($PNAME -eq "explorer") -or ($PNAME -eq "init") -or ($PNAME -eq "sshd") ) {
            # Write-Host ": non-interactive" -fore Cyan
            break;
        }
        ""
    }
}
```

**How can I check if the profile script is running from within a remote SSH session?**

<sub>Why am I doing this? Because I want to disable the script from running automatically through SSH/SCP/SFTP, while still being able to run it manually (still over SSH.) In Bash this is a trivial one-liner.</sub>

---

Some related (but unhelpful) answers:

- [Powershell test for noninteractive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738535/powershell-test-for-noninteractive-mode)
- [How to check if a Powershell script is running remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394196/how-to-check-if-a-powershell-script-is-running-remotely)
- [Powershell - detect whether running in interactive mode or not](https://superuser.com/questions/1621096/powershell-detect-whether-running-in-interactive-mode-or-not) (Superuser SO)

Comment: Isn't the `-noprofile` option pointless though? `PSRemoting over SSH does not support Profiles and does not have access to $PROFILE. Once in a session, you can load a profile by dot sourcing the profile with the full filepath.` [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core)

Comment: Yeah, but I am not using the native windows remoting. Also using cross-platform access and other types of connections based on ssh, but not (only) using open-ssh for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe I am handling this particular case in my PowerShell profile by checking the value of `[System.Console]::IsOutputRedirected`.

I have a bunch of code in `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` that I want to run only in an interactive session, both when started locally as well as through SSH.

ie. When I run a command over SSH on my remote windows host, like so:

```bash
ssh user@winhost C:\\PROGRA~1\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command Get-ChildItem
```

This will execute my PowerShell profile `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` automatically before running the `Get-ChildItem` command. Inside of my PowerShell profile, I am checking the value of `[System.Console]::IsOutputRedirected` which returns true in this case. So when it returns true I return early and skip executing all the logic specific to initializing my interactive PowerShell session (command completion, keybindings, terminal colors, etc).

Conversely, when I SSH into PowerShell on the remote windows host interactively, like so:

```bash
ssh user@winhost C:\\PROGRA~1\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
```

This also executes my PowerShell profile `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` automatically before dropping me into an interactive PowerShell session, but in this case, when I check the value of `[System.Console]::IsOutputRedirected` it returns false, and I allow the script to continue running to setup my PowerShell profile for an interactive session.

**Note:** The above logic handles that particular case when it comes to executing over SSH, however, to handle various different possible ways to run PowerShell interactively, I've had to check additional cases. My current logic for handling all possible cases regarding interactivity is the following:

```
if ([System.Console]::IsOutputRedirected -or ![Environment]::UserInteractive -or !!([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() | Where-Object { $_ -ilike '-noni*' })) {
    // Non-Interactive
}
```

See:

- [Console.IsOutputRedirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.isoutputredirected?view=net-7.0)
- [Environment.UserInteractive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userinteractive?view=net-7.0)
- [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=net-7.0)

Comment: This looks promising. I haven't needed to use this for a while, so I still need to test your solution. IIRC, the main problem was when you were using other tools that use SSH. For example when using SSH via `WinSCP`, or from a non-Posh shell like `GitBash,` or Cygwin `mintty/bash` etc. Or when remoting into your Windows machine from a *nix based OS. Have you tried any that?

Comment: @not2qubit Yeah, in the examples I gave above, I tested those commands by using ssh to connect to a remote windows host from a client linux machine running bash shell on Ubuntu Server 22.04 — though the same commands and logic for checking interactivity should also work if using ssh to connect to a remote windows host from a client that is also running windows using either pwsh or cmd shell.

Comment: Pasting the test condition in the above line in an interactive shell, returns `False`... Seem to be something wrong with the last test condition. Also why are you using double *negation* (`!!`) there?

Comment: @not2qubit The condition in the if statement above is expected to return False in an interactive shell. As indicated by the comment, it will return true when the shell is _not_ interactive. The double negation is just a cast to a boolean value, turning truthy values into True and falsey values into False, it may not be strictly required.

Comment: I think at one point I was returning that last bit of the conditional from a function and wanted the function to actually return true or false and so was casting it to be so. Probably could be removed, but that's what I'm currently using. It's not hurting anything though, aside from being potentially redundant.

Comment: Yes, it also works without the `!!`. I didn't know double `!!` would turn it into a cast. Is that documented somewhere or yet another hidden windows trick?

Comment: Nah, that's actually not language specific. It's an implicit cast, rather than an explicit cast. In most languages, using the unary boolean not operator (!) will implicitly cast it's operand to a boolean. This is what makes if statements work properly when checking variables that are not strictly boolean values, such as checking whether an integer is zero with `if (!someInteger) { ... }` or checking if a string is empty or a value is null/undefined with something like `if (!someEmptyString) { ... }` or `if (!someNullVariable) { ... }`.

Comment: @not2qubit In those examples, the unary not operator implicitly casts to a boolean value which makes the if statement work properly even though the variable isn't actually a true boolean variable. In addition to the implicit cast, a single unary not operator (!) obviously also has the primary effect of negating the "truthiness" of it's operand. So, a double unary not operator (!!) negates the "truthiness" of it's operand twice, effectively cancelling the negation, and leaving only an implicit cast to boolean.